# Add input fields times two based on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on a select dropdown value I add some textfields dynamically. 
I can get that to work, however based on the select value the input fields need to be added times two. 
So If select value equals 1 then there should be 2 input fields added. The two input fields should have a different placeholder value.

I can get this to work on first load of the page. But when I change the select again then it shows the amount of input fields minus 2 or minus 1. So when select value is 2 then it shows 3 or 2 input fields instead of 4.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<select name="custom[3426980]" id="graveren">
    <option value="" data-amount="0" selected="selected">No thx!</option>
    <option value="28714790" data-amount="1">Some value 1</option>
    <option value="28714791" data-amount="2">Some value 2</option>
    <option value="28714792" data-amount="3">Some value 3</option>                 
        // etc etc....            
</select>
<div id="steps"></div>

function addTextBoxes(){
    var count = $('#graveren option:selected').data('amount');
    $('#steps input:gt('+(count-2)+')').remove();
    if(count !== 0){
      for (var i = $('#steps input').length; i < count; i++){
        var html = '<input type="text" placeholder="Bead '+(i+1)+' front" value="" /><input type="text" placeholder="Bead '+(i+1)+' back" value="" />' 
        $(html).appendTo('#graveren #steps');
      }
    } else {
      $('#steps input').remove();
    }
  }

$(function(){
    addTextBoxes();        
    $('#graveren select').on('change', function(){
            addTextBoxes();
    });
});
```

Comment: Little bit confusing what you're trying to do.  You're comparing `$(#steps input).length` with `data-amount`, but you're always adding 2 inputs for each count.  ie, on first you select 4, it creates 8 inputs.  then select 3 so it removes inputs `:gt(3-2)` - (why -2 here?)  ie all of but 1, but they come in pairs (maybe should be `:gt((count*2)-2)?`).  then runs the loop based on remaining number of inputs to the count `1..3` (ie 2) so adds another 4 inputs (2x2) giving 5 in total...

Comment: Maybe just change `var count = $('#graveren option:selected').data('amount');` to `var count = $('#graveren option:selected').data('amount'); * 2` and in the for `i++` to `i+=2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in the logic itself. Corrected your logic. See if it helps.

```
 function addTextBoxes(){
var count = $('#graveren option:selected').data('amount');
var removeCount = 2*count-1;
$('#steps input:gt('+removeCount+')').remove();
if(count !== 0){

  for (var i = $('#steps input').length/2; i < count; i++){
    var html = '<input type="text" placeholder="Bead '+(i+1)+' front" value="" /><input type="text" placeholder="Bead '+(i+1)+' back" value="" />' 
    $(html).appendTo('#steps');
  }
} else {
  $('#steps input').remove();
}
  }

 $(function(){
addTextBoxes();        
$('#graveren').change(function(){
        addTextBoxes();
});
 });
```

Comment: Ok this works! Can you perhaps give some more info on why you did `2*count-1`?? Why `-1`?

Comment: Because for every count, you are adding 2 text boxes. So, when removing text boxes, you need to make sure that you are keeping 2*count text boxes and deleting all other text boxes. Here index starts from 0 so we are keeping 2*count-1 text boxes and deleting all other boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
$('#graveren select').on('change', function(){
  addTextBoxes();
});
```

You are looking for select inside select with id "graveren". Just change it to:

```
$('#graveren').on('change', function(){
```

I found another problem here: you are appending to `$(html).appendTo('#graveren #steps');` element with id "step", which is nested to element with id "graveren". But you have no element with id "steps" you your select with id "graveren"... Just change this line:

```
$(html).appendTo('#graveren #steps');
```

to:

```
$(html).appendTo('#steps');
```

And your code will work... Complete example:

```js
function addTextBoxes(){
  var count = $('#graveren option:selected').data('amount');
  $('#steps input:gt('+(count-2)+')').remove();
  if(count !== 0){
    for (var i = $('#steps input').length; i < count; i++){
      var html = '<input type="text" placeholder="Bead '+(i+1)+' front" value="" /><input type="text" placeholder="Bead '+(i+1)+' back" value="" />' 
      $(html).appendTo('#steps');
    }
  } else {
    $('#steps input').remove();
  }
}

$(function(){
  addTextBoxes();        
  $('select#graveren').on('change', function(){
    addTextBoxes();
  });
});
```

```html
<select name="custom[3426980]" id="graveren">
  <option value="" data-amount="0" selected="selected">No thx!</option>
  <option value="28714790" data-amount="1">Some value 1</option>
  <option value="28714791" data-amount="2">Some value 2</option>
  <option value="28714792" data-amount="3">Some value 3</option>     </select>

<div id="steps"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. Your example is exactly what goes wrong :) When I select "some value 2" is should open 4 inputs. Where every two inputs is a pair. So if value is 2. Then 4 inputs should open where every two inputs is paired to the value.

Comment: @Meules So, not only the selectors, but the logic in addTextBoxes() function is wrong also?